# SVG bg-image doesn't work well with safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, safari

I know there might be plenty of other topics about SVG background-images and browser compatibility, but i really can't find out any solution to my problem. I'm using Foundation 5.

So, I've got three divs in a row. Each div has a svg as a bg-image.

See, on Chrome, works perfectly:
[Chrome capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgW5O.jpg)

The svg background isn't the bubble itself but the surrounding, that I filled with blue ( so bg-color is white ).

But if I go on Safari, there is a small white line on the border of my divs : [Safari capture](http://imgur.com/ktT3b1v)

I'd like to get rid of this white line on safari. I mean, I want my row to display as in Chrome. So, I know background images width in safari are set in px, and that mine are set with %. But I don't really think it has something to do with it. I really have no idea of how I can resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D ! I didn't really know how to put it the right way .. Sorry if I missed something

Comment: We really need to see a demo so Safari users can test it for you, JSfiddle.net is good for that.

Comment: Hmm... will it handle Foundation css ?

Comment: We don't need the whole page...just a **reduced case** demo that replicates the proble,...but sure, you'll probably have to link the Foundation CSS through a CDN like [CloudflareCDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundation/)

Comment: Hm okay i'll see what i can do ( no need to tell i'm a beginner :p)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your attention, but after two days I resolved the problem. I had to add the viewbox attribute to display my bg correctly. Thanks anyway!